# Properties of some family of subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $X$ be a linear space (without topology), over field of real or complex numbers.

Let $B$ be a family of subsets of $X$ satisfying conditions:

1. sets from $B$ are balansed and absorbing (in particular each of them contains zero);
2. if $V_1, V_2 \in B$ then there exists $V\in B$ such that $V\subset V_1 \cap V_2$;
3. if $V\in B$ then there exists $W\in B$ such that $W+W \subset V$;
4. if $V\in B$ and $a\neq 0$ then there exists $W\in B$ such that $W\subset aV$.

Let $B(x):=\{x+V: V \in B \}$.

Is it then true that

if $V\in B(x)$ and $y \in V$ then there exists $U\in B(y)$ such that $U\subset V$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $B = \{ [-a,\,a] : a > 0\}$. However, if $V \in B(x)$, then there is a $W \in B(x)$, such that for all $y \in W$ there exists a $U \in B(y)$ with $U \subset V$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Make it an answer?

Comment: @CameronBuie I'll wait for a couple of minutes if the OP posts "Oh, I have forgotten some additional condition" before I make it an answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree with CameronBuie's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These conditions do not guarantee that for all $V \in B(x)$ and $y \in V$ there is a $U\in B(y)$ with $U \subset V$.

As a simple counterexample, consider the set of symmetric closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$,

$$B = \{ [-a,\,a] : a > 0\}.$$

Then each $B(x)$ is a neighbourhood basis of closed neighbourhoods, and for $V \in B(x)$, and $y \in \partial V \subset V$, there is no $U \in B(y)$ that is contained in $V$.

When you have a topological vector space $X$, the same "problem" arises if $B$ is a family of closed neighbourhoods of $0$ (or even if it contains any neighbourhood of $0$ that is not open).

However, the conditions ensure that the family $B$ defines a TVS topology $\tau_B$ on $X$, and $B(x)$ is a neighbourhood basis at $x$ for $\tau_B$, so

$$\bigl(\forall V \in B(x)\bigr) \bigl(\exists W \in B(0)\bigr) \bigl(\forall y \in (x+W)\bigr) \bigl(y+W \subset V\bigr).$$